# Reassign Joystick path

Tags: tablet, joystick, wacom

So, I have a 'Wacom_Co._Ltd._Cintiq_13HD_Touch_Tablet'. The kernel thinks it is a joystick, so `/dev/input/js0` gets assigned to this.

Now I want to play a game, and it is (understandably) looking for a joystick at `js0`, but that is where the tablet is, not my joystick (which is at `js1`).

Is there a way to tell the kernel to assign the tablet to something like `js10` so a real joystick/controller gets assigned to `js0`? I have tried messing with udev rules by making a `/etc/udev/rules.d/73-persistent-joystick.rules`, but the syslog gives this error:

> NAME="input/js9" ignored, kernel device nodes can not be renamed; please fix it in `/etc/udev/rules.d/73-persistent-joystick.rules:1`

Note: currently, I am running this workaround before starting the game:

> cd /dev/input; sudo sh -c "mv js0 js10; mv js1 js0"

Comment: You'll want to play wtih `udev` rules, assuming you are using a relatively recent Linux distribution

Comment: https://github.com/denilsonsa/udev-joystick-blacklist

Comment: Note you never **rename** original device nodes in udev rules, instead, you create **symlinks** with static names. Look at `/dev/disks` for examples, do something similar for your joystick (`/dev/js/wacom`, `/dev/js/real-joystick`, whatever). If your game only looks for `js0`, it's broken.